# Left and right divs are not working correctly?

Tags: css

I am trying to have one div on the left side of the page, and one div on the right side of the page.

The code ([Code Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Abijah/x2r4P/2/)) works fine when it's in jsFiddle; however, when I use the same code on my website the "right" div doesn't float to the right, doesn't have a border, and it places itself above the "left" div.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "on my website"?

Comment: Do you have the page online anywhere else besides in jsFiddle?

Comment: How are we meant to advise you on the problem when we can't see where the problem is? I'd suggest that you might want to use a CSS reset stylesheet, as that's one thing that JS Fiddle includes by default (though it can be removed by unticking a check-box on the left).

Comment: What browser + version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have many issues to solve in order to present the web page properly cross-browser, but to give you a solution for the problem at hand, you can see this [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/x2r4P/4/)

**THE RELEVANT CSS**

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

**THE RELEVANT HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div id="right">Right!</div>
  <div id="left">Left!</div>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

Wrap the `#left` and `#right` into a div that uses the class `clearfix` to clear the document flow at that specific point.
That should allow the `#right` and `#left` to be on their proper place with or without a CSS Reset applied to your web page.

---

**Get a CSS Reset for HTML5:** http://html5reset.org/

**Read about Floated Elements:** [CSS Float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)  |  [CSS float Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)